# How to combine the numeric variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

> I have quite an issue here, I am looking to make the space in between the 
>   numbers disappear, and by that I mean to put the 3 numbers together (combine them not ADD) and make it 1 string only.
>  Can someone have a look at my code and see what I can improve? I have been trying all sorts of things but end up with a space in between the numbers.

```
:start
REM Random numbers generator


:nr1
echo %RANDOM:~-1% > First.cdb
set /p first=<First.cdb


:nr2
echo %RANDOM:~-1% > Second.cdb
set /p second=<Second.cdb
if %second%==%first% goto :nr2


:nr3
echo %RANDOM:~-1% > Third.cdb
set /p third=<Third.cdb
if %third%==%first% (
goto :nr3
)
if %third%==%second% (
goto :nr3
)

:output
cls
echo Output
echo.
echo %first%%second%%third%


:combiner


pause
goto :start
```

The output should be something like the following:

> 123
>   I get it to look like this:
>   1 2 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your issue appears to be that you're `echo`ing a trailing space yourself when you don't need to `echo` anything to a file in the first place.*

The following would probably set the variable `%Num%`'s string value to a randomly generated string consisting of three unique digits.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Num="
:Loop
For %%A In (%RANDOM:~-1%) Do Echo("!Num!"|Find "%%A">Nul||Set "Num=!Num!%%A"
If 1%Num% Lss 1012 GoTo Loop
Echo(%Num%
Pause
```

**Edit**

You may find that this simple example, without the `For` loop better matches your intent:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "first=%RANDOM:~-1%"
:Loop1
Set "second=%RANDOM:~-1%"
If "%second%"=="%first%" GoTo Loop1
:Loop2
Set "third=%RANDOM:~-1%"
If Not "%third%"=="%second%" If Not "%third%"=="%first%" GoTo Result
GoTo Loop2
:Result
Echo(%first%%second%%third%
Pause
```

Comment: Awesome! 

Just need to make them 1 string ONLY so that I can use them as a whole unit.
I need them to be able to be 1 number so that I can use them in mathematical ways

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: instead of `echo %RANDOM:~-1% > First.cdb` use

```
> First.cdb echo %RANDOM:~-1%
```

But, if you want a random number between 000 and 999 you can use:

```
SET n=00%RANDOM%
SET n=%n:~-3%
ECHO %n%
```

Somewhat further: assuming `%RANDOM%` follows a uniform distribution between 0 and 32767, you can grant an uniform distribution between `000` and `999` using:

```
:AVOID_BAD_NUMBER
SET N=00%RANDOM%
IF %N% GEQ 32000 GOTO:AVOID_BAD_NUMBER
SET n=%n:~-3%
ECHO %n%
```

Otherway numbers between 0-767 would be a little bit more probable than 768-999!

Comment: Great, I got rid of the spacing, BUT I would like to combine the 3 digits and put them together to make 1 whole number.

So 1 2 3 would be 123, and NOT just visually.
Please add this to the comment you made.

Comment: There'd be no need to do this: `> First.cdb echo %RANDOM:~-1%` at all, the logical way would be to use: `Set "first=%RANDOM:~-1%"` Also the OP appears to be wanting only numbers containing three different integers which isn't what your code does!

Comment: Also you should be using best practice of `SET "VARIABLE=VALUE"` and there's no such comparison operator as `GTE`.